# Swift - NSTimer to loop through array with delay

Tags: ios, arrays, animation, swift, nstimer

I have an array, and I wish to set the text of a UILabel to an element of the array, and then after a second set the text as the next element of the array. Once the end of the array has been reached, it needs to then return to the start. I have tried completing this with a for loop that runs through the array, with a delay function inside the for loop, but this does not slow down the operation of the for loop itself. I have also tried using an NSTimer,

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func update() {
    var i = Int()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.3, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in

        if i == connectionName.count - 1 {
            i = 0
            println(connectionName[i])
        } else {
            println(connectionName[i])
        }

        }, completion:  { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            i = i+1
    })

}
```

But I just get an error

```
2015-01-08 15:06:10.511 Tinder[585:10642] -[Tinder.TinderViewController update]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae99ead3f0
2015-01-08 15:06:10.612 Tinder[585:10642] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tinder.TinderViewController update]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae99ead3f0'
```

Is this because the function is defined within the view did load method?

Comment: Maybe Xcode swiped left on your app.

Comment: Is `func update()` a *nested* function within `viewDidLoad`? That cannot work.

Comment: put func update() outside viewDidLoad in the scope of the class.

Comment: I have moved func update() outside viewdidload and now it works. I thought this may be the case, I expected that xcode would have given me an error if it was the wrong thing to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked

> Is this because the function is defined within the view did load method?

That is indeed the problem. `NSTimer` uses Objective-C messaging to call the timer function, and
nested functions in Swift are not exposed as Objective-C methods.
You have to define `update()` as a top-level function within the view controller class.

Unfortunately, the compiler cannot warn you, because it does not "know" that the
string "update" in the selector corresponds to the `update()` function. (Unlike the Objective-C `@selector()`, Swift uses simple strings as selectors, and the compiler
cannot verify its existence).

If you explicitly annotate a nested function with `@objc` then you will get a 
compiler error.